# Is it possible to add your own content in the sidebar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to make an extension that adds a View to the scm view container. I want to add a few fields /select drop downs in a view but I only find tutorials on how to make a tree... I tried abusing a tree item in the hope that I could render what I wanted but the tree item seems to render just its label.

Is there any way to add arbitrary content to a sidebar view? Anyone know of any existing extension that does this that I could look at?

Comment: No, it's limited to tree views at the moment.